# Set y aesthetic as the number of rows of dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2

I made the graph below using ggplot:

```
ggplot(subset(monthly.rate, year=="2015"), aes(x=a6ncopo)) + geom_bar()
```

[image: graph]

Here the number of observations at each time point (and therefore the number of rows) are being summed for each time point.

I want to make the same graph but using geom_line to make a line graph. But of course I get the error 'requires the following missing aesthetics: y'.

How do I get ggplot2 to plot a line graph using the number of rows on the y axis, the same way it easily handles using geom_bar?

Dput:

```
(removed)
```

Comment: can you give an example data?

Comment: Yes OK, one second

Comment: @Learner OK I have given a dput

Comment: I suppose your dput is just a subset, because it does not produce the same output... Anyway, a quick way to do what you want is to add `stat="count"` to your `geom_line`.

Comment: Sorry! the time is a6ncopo, the axis labels have just been changed.

Comment: @Samuel Harper This works just fine, calling your data as `df` ggplot(subset(df, year=="2015"), aes(x=a6ncopo)) + geom_bar() +geom_line (stat="count")

Answer (score 0):

Answered in comments:

```
ggplot(subset(df, year=="2015"), aes(x=a6ncopo)) + 
    geom_bar() +
    geom_line(stat="count")
```